# How to add an existing recipe to a custom BSP layer in Yocto

Tags: layer, yocto, recipe

I'm new to Yocto. I have a custom BSP layer. I need to add an existing recipe to it. My layer needs to have `libevent` and `libsoc` in it.

How do I add them to it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libevent libsoc"` in `local.conf` as explained on the [manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-customimage-localconf).